# Redirect to other dialogflow agent?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I got started with dialogflow two weeks ago, and have a good basic understanding of how everything works. I'm trying to do the following:

I have one agent, which should take a query from the user (more like a keyword in a sentence, for example *"I'd like to buy a **phone**"* or *"I'd like to get a **loan**"*).

This query should go to a system which has a list of chatbots registered. It has to find the best matched agent for the query.

My question is, how do I redirect from the initial chatbot (which listens to the query) to the 'final' agent?

Is there a blogpost, documentation or something similar for this? I was unfortunately not able to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can use your base agent's webhook as a dispatcher to relay a message to another agent the same way you would do it with `curl`.

We took another approach where we're using a middleware in front of DialogFlow that does the dispatching based on a base agent's response.

Once the base agent returns another agent to our middleware, we use the event system to query that specific agent's welcome intent and return it back to the UI.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think I understand it, but am still having difficulties to find a resource to learn from.. Could you maybe help me with find a resource for curl you're talking about? Or maybe code example? I really tried but couldn't find it.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there are not many resources to learn how to do that at the moment.

Start with this: https://dialogflow.com/docs/how-tos/getting-started-fulfillment and try to go as far as you can. Come back with your results here.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work! Will document this somewhere to help generating resources for others to learn about this.

Comment: @JanvanDijk yaay ! You should add your working solution here as an answer :)